# Regarding Usages matrix and rotate at a time

Tags: css

Can i use matrix and rotate at a time, i will allready try that but it was not supported in my brower.

I use below css in my css file. Could any one please check and let me know any thing is problem found.

```
-moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
-o-transform:matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
transform: rotate(-180deg);
display:block;
```

Regards,
Biswojit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to set it in the same property

```
-webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) rotate(-180deg);    
transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) rotate(-180deg);
```

You can not specify the same property 2 times, and expect that both are applied.